# what should be the configuration of hive-site.xml?

Tags: jsp, hadoop, hive

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
```

My hive worked **fine untill i run a jsp file in eclipse** to perform queries.But when i started running my jsp file on tomcat server it displays an semantic error that the table does'nt exist.And i come back to terminal and verify my database it displays as above.I am using **standalone mode**.What should me hive-site.xml or else is there any issue with metastore_db..?
plzz kindly anyone suggest me..

Comment: I tried solutions of similar problem but they haven't helped...kindly suggest me.thank u

Comment: when i add hive-site.xml in hive/conf  the above error is comming..plz help me

Comment: I am desperately in need please anyone help me....